# What is the role of $state.go('.')?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am unsure about the behaviour of state.go with '.' parameter. Does it reload the current state?

**Edit:** It was just reloading the current state.

Comment: use $state.reload();

Answer (score 1):

It looks in the state configuration for a state called '.'. If it finds one, it will go to the path as specified in that configuration.